# Python import from parent directory for dockerize structure

Tags: python-3.x, python-import

I have a project with two applications. They both use a mongo-engine database model file. Also they have to start in different Docker containers, but use the same Mongo database in the fird container. Now my app structure looks like this:

```
app_root/
   app1/
      database/
         models.py
      main.py
   app2/
      database/
         models.py
      main.py
```

And it works fine, BUT I have to support two same files database/models.py. I dont want to do this and I make the next structure:

```
app_root/
   shared/
      database/
         models.py
   app1/
      main.py
   app2/
      main.py
```

Unfortunately it doesnt work for me, because when I try this in my main.py:

```
from ..shared.database.models import *
```

I get

```
Exception has occurred: ImportError 
attempted relative import with no known parent package
```

And when I try

```
from app_root.shared.database.models import *
```

I get

```
Exception has occurred: ModuleNotFoundError No module named 'app_root'
```

Please, what do I do wrong?

Comment: Try adding an empty `__init__.py` at each level and try again the import with absolute path.

Comment: I tryed, "no module name" error

Comment: Is this just a typo in the question? `import app_root.shared.database.models import *` instead of `from app_root... import ...`

Comment: yes, sorry, its just a type. edited

Comment: You can add the container absolute path to the module to `$PYTHONPATH`, or do a `WORKDIR /your/absolute/path/` inside Dockerfile (https://www.educative.io/edpresso/what-is-the-workdir-command-in-docker).

Comment: @Niloct yes, but its not about Docker. Im OK with it. The question is about import in Python, I cant import shared module. That would be nice for running apps locally

Comment: The only way to import your module without tweaking path is to invoke python on the directory that has the app_root.py file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the file you perform the import, try adding this:

```
import os
import sys
sys.path.append(os.path.abspath('../../..'))

from app_root.shared.database.models import *
```

Comment: I see. It adds my project dir to PATH variable, but Is it the best solution in Python?

Comment: And why does Python have a dot(..) syntax in imports like from ..shared.database import *

Comment: Two dots means up one package level. Check out the docs [here](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/simple_stmts.html#the-import-statement).

Comment: *"Is it the best solution in Python?"* I believe it is the more generic solution to your problem, without modifying the `__init__.py` files.